# SignalR in SSE Mode: Meaning of EventSource readyState Property

Tags: signalr, server-sent-events

What is the meaning of these entries in the SignalR client-side logs?

EventSource readyState: 0

(then, after 20-30 minutes of 0's, they all switch to 2's and SignalR stops communicating until I refresh the page)

EventSource readyState: 2

Answer (score 1):

There are three readystates for EventSource.

```
0 = Connecting
1 = Open
2 = Closed
```

0 can refer to both connecting or reconnecting.  Does your connection ever show a readystate of 1?  Does the server and client connect and communicate at all successfully?  I'm not sure if SignalR displays a 1 or shows a connection made event within the log.  I would imagine there is an issue with your server and client communication that is not being established correctly if its stuck in readystate 0.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-eventsource-20110208/#the-eventsource-interface

Comment: I never see a readystate of 1 (at least, not from the SignalR client logs).  However, the app appears to work correctly, receiving notifications initiated by other connected clients, for periods as long as 20-30 minutes or longer.  Something mysterious always happens and then readyState starts showing all 2's and notifications are no longer received.

Comment: I see.  If its working for 20-30 minutes, there is some unknown reason why your client is disconnected.  The readystate of 2 just indicates the connection was lost.  I would try to contain both the server/client to the same machine and run it locally to pinpoint exactly what might be causing the disconnection.  If you feel I've been able to answer your question to the best of the information given, please upvote/mark as answer.